# app had used up 28% of battery in 45 minutes

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, battery

my application consuming more battery, it is using more battery in one hour it using around 30%.
 how to handle it.
I don't have any idea about it.

Thanks,

Comment: You should write major functionality of your application so that someone can help!! like your application is using location continuously or something else!

Comment: Do you mean an application that you wrote? If so, generally speaking, the more you use your hard drive - the faster you use up your battery. This also includes if your application is being swapped out to the hard drive because it is big enough that the operating system is doing the swapping. You should post more information about both your program as well as the computer you are using. Remember that the more resources you use - the faster the battery is used up. :-)

Comment: Yes, i am getting location continuously, What is the solution for it? @KetanParmar

Comment: Whether you are getting location continuously, the battery could not reduced so fast like that

Comment: Use the energy instruments tool

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do things like:
1.  Turn location services on only when they are  needed.
2. You can reduce the location Accuracy.
Refer this [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/LocationBestPractices.html)